# minitoc suppress title and rules

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

There are a few questions already about `minitoc`. But I could not find a way to suppress/disable the "Contents" title of the `minitoc` and the `hrules`...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc

\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}

The following topics will be explored:
\minitoc

\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}` sets an empty title (i.e. no title)
- `\mtcsetrules{*}{off}`, all rules in the various `ToC`s are disabled then.
- If the `minitoc` is too much to the right margin, use `\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-4.0em}` then (change `-4.0em` to some value at will)
- If `mtcsetoffset` isn't the right tool, use
  `\setlength{\mtcindent}{-1.5em}` instead, which sets the indentation of the toc as well. (`-1.5em` again being a pure guess value here)

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc

\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}
%\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-4.0em}  % To shift the minitoc to the left, if needed!
\setlength{\mtcindent}{-1.5em}
\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}

The following topics will be explored:
\minitoc

\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The ToC is indented too much, in my opinion

Comment: I am using an one-depth minitoc (`\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}`), and would like to not have indentations in the sections. This is not working for me: `\setlength{\stcindent}{0pt}`. The problem with `\mtcsetoffset` is that it moves the entire minitoc (including pages) to the left. Do you know how I could just disable the indentation?  (many, many thanks btw!)

Comment: @RicardoCruz: I'll try, give me some time

Comment: @RicardoCruz: See the update. `\stcindent` is only available in a `secttoc` which conflicts with `report.cls`, as far as I have understood the manual/error messages of the package

Comment: Perfect! I had to do a combination between `\mtcindent` and `\mtcsetoffset` because `\mtcindent` would enlarge the minitoc ... But it is just as I wanted now! Thank you!