# How to remove horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I remove the horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the TOC of the appendix?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{minitoc}

% Make the "Part I" text invisible
\renewcommand \thepart{}
\renewcommand \partname{}


\begin{document}
\doparttoc % Tell to minitoc to generate a toc for the parts
\faketableofcontents % Run a fake tableofcontents command for the partocs

\part{} % Start the document part
%\parttoc % Insert the document TOC

\section{First}
First content.
\section{Second}
Second content.

\newpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix} % Add the appendix text to the document TOC
\part{Appendix} % Start the appendix part
\parttoc % Insert the appendix TOC

\section{Appendix First}
Appendix first content.
\section{Appendix Second}
Appendix second content.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See this response
[in StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268205/minitoc-suppress-title-and-rules) ;Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command provided by minitoc package

```
\noptcrule
```

your code will be

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage[]{minitoc}
\noptcrule %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
% Make the "Part I" text invisible
\renewcommand \thepart{}
\renewcommand \partname{}


\begin{document}
\doparttoc % Tell to minitoc to generate a toc for the parts
\faketableofcontents % Run a fake tableofcontents command for the partocs

\part{} % Start the document part
%\parttoc % Insert the document TOC

\section{First}
First content.
\section{Second}
Second content.

\newpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix} % Add the appendix text to the document TOC
\part{Appendix} % Start the appendix part
\parttoc % Insert the appendix TOC

\section{Appendix First}
Appendix first content.
\section{Appendix Second}
Appendix second content.

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By doc of `minitoc`, Sec. 1.5.1, a "simpler" way is to use command `\mtcsetrules` as follows:

```
\mtcsetrules{parttoc}{off}
```