# Cannot use minitoc package with offset

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, indentation, minitoc

I am currently writing a report in LaTex.

I am encountering a puzzling issue... I have looked on stackexchange and cannot find a way to solve my problem.

Main source I found: [minitoc suppress title and rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268205/minitoc-suppress-title-and-rules)

---

I try to run and compile a similar looking tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc

%\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-1.0em}    %% If I uncomment, I have errors
\setlength{\mtcindent}{-0.75em}

\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}

The following topics will be explored:
\minitoc

\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I basically try to remove the indent within the minitoc and center it.
The best solution seem to be a combination of \mtcindent and \mtcsetoffset, however, if I uncomment the line commented below, I obtain the following errors:

```
line 7: Missing \begin{document}. \mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-1.0em}
line 7: Extra \endcsname. \mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-1.0em}
line 7: Extra \else. \mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-1.0em}
line 7: Package minitoc Error: E0043(minitoc) \mtcsetoffset: Illegal type of table (minitoc). \mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-1.0em}
line 7: Extra \fi. \mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-1.0em}
```

I compile with the following command:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --aux-directory=build  --output-directory=compiled %.tex
```

I have checked, all my packages are up to date at the current date 04/11/2018.

I have identified that the error seems to come from MikTeX, the packages causing the error are the following:

[image]

Comment: You could try `\renewcommand{\mtcoffset}{-1em}` as a workaround.

Comment: It seems that a package was updated and lead to an error. I installed an old version of Miktex with an old version of my packages it seems to work. However, there is still a package raising this error if you install the latest version of MikTeX.

I cannot try the fix, I don't have this version anymore installed

Comment: @esdd It seems that I have more or less identified the packages leading to this error.