# Adding a list of sections of chapter in sidenotes

Tags: sidenotes

I want to have a simple toc in the sidenotes, which looks like the following picture.

[image]

I tried minitoc, but it is too wide for the margin, also, it doesn't look like the above picture. I don't know how to delete the extra spacing, the horizontal lines and "Contents". Is there any method to add a list of sections in sidenotes without using minitoc?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\textheight}{700pt}%598,674
\setlength{\textwidth}{325pt}%325
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{180pt}%+20+9%180
\setlength{\voffset}{-51pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth-0.5\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-1in}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\chapter{123}
\marginpar{\minitoc}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction2}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

After adding three lines:

```
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{-1.5em}
```

There are still problems, first, the width is not correct, second, I don't know how to remove the dots between section title and page number. I also found that it is not compatible with titlesec.(I didn't notice this problem so I didn't include titlesec in MWE, sorry.) (W0099(minitoc(hints)) --- The titlesec package is loaded. (minitoc(hints)) It is incompatible (minitoc(hints)) with the minitoc package.)

**UPDATE 2**
Finally I use \label{} and \nameref{} to achieve this. I add label after each section and use nameref to get their names.

```
 \marginpar{1.1\hfill\nameref{1-1}\\%
    1.2\hfill\nameref{1-2}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [minitoc suppress title and rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268205/minitoc-suppress-title-and-rules)

Comment: @Marijn it still can't solve the width problem. I get "overfull hbox(145.0pt too wide)"

Comment: That is a warning, not an error - if you are happy with the result then you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: @Marijn How to remove the dots?

Comment: `\mtcsetformat{minitoc}{dotinterval}{450}` should do that (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/minitoc.pdf) on page 45).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. I used \label{}, \nameref{} and tabularx. I used tabularx because it is suitable forlong section title. MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\textheight}{700pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{325pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{180pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-51pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth-0.5\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-1in}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{123}
\marginpar{%
    \begin{tabularx}{180pt}{cX}
        \leavevmode\\
        \textbf{1-1} & \nameref{1-1}\\
        \textbf{1-2} & \nameref{1-2}\\
        \textbf{1-3} & \nameref{1-3}\\
    \end{tabularx}%
}%
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction}\label{1-1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction2}\label{1-2}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction3}\label{1-3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```